# Need to get order details from two range of date

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get order details from range of dates(from date and To date)
For that i am using below code but i am not getting

[image]

while printing order collection, i am getting a long array....
i need to get order detail like email id,product details.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think only problem with you variable add `time` with them..

```
include('../../../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$fromDate='2016-3-5 00:00:00';
$tomDate='2016-3-10 00:00:00';
```

Comment: after changing the format,not getting any result

Comment: updated the code add these line too and make sure you have correct path of `Mage.php`

Comment: while printing (print_r($or)) , nothing print....blank only.If we are printing(print_r($orderCollection)), a long array printing. starting with Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_order_collection
    [_eventObject:protected] => order_collection
    [_model:protected] => sales/order
    [_resourceModel:protected] => sales/order
    [_resource:protected] => Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order Object
        (

Comment: `echo $or;  ` and `print_r($orderCollection->getData());` will show you result.

Comment: giving result : Array
(
)

Comment: change date and see they make any difference i tested this and working for me..

Comment: still i am getting blank array...Array ( )

Answer (score 1):

Your code as below

```
    $from_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2016-3-5));
    $to_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime(2016-3-10));

    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

    foreach($orderCollection as $order){
       $order->getCustomerEmail();
       $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach($items as $i){
         echo $i->getProductId();
       }
    }
```

hope it will helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can use Zend_Date objects.

```
$fromDate = new Zend_Date('2016-3-5');
$toDate = new Zend_Date('2016-3-10');
```

And use these parameters in your filter

```
... array('from'=>$fromDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT),
      'to'=>$toDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT)) ...
```

And to check your query is ok you have to invoke the __toString method of the collection select

```
echo $orderCollection->getSelect();
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring this answer up to date using the datetime object - this example gets orders between 01.01.2018 and today.

```
    $_fromDate = new \DateTime('2018-01-01');
    $_toDate = new \DateTime();

    $_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$_fromDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'to'=>$_toDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ;
```